# Connecting air compressor hose to ball valve drain port

Tags: plumbing

I have a ball valve similar to what is pictured below with a drain port:

[image: ball valve with drain port]

I would like to buy or somehow assemble an adapter that connects the drain port pictured with an air compressor quick coupling hose connection, but am unsure about how to go about doing this. Is there a ready made part that would fit the bill, or search terms I should be using to identify the parts I need to make a custom assembly?

Thank you

Comment: Will the air pressure be comparable with water supply pressure?  Keep in mind that this is not designed for air, so it may leak.

Comment: Yea, I'm realizing that because of the threading, pushing air through this valve at ~40-50 PSI may not actually be feasible.

Comment: There are ball valves used with compressed air; my compressors use them as drain valves. Get one of those and adapt the threads on the _other_ side if necessary?

Comment: I have a feeling the right thing to do is to tee off the pipe and add a dedicated valve + adapter intended for pushing air through, yea.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it something you'd leave connected? Or just to blow water out of the line once in a while?

Comment: Blowing water out of the line is the primary reason yea